# 64 bit web browsers

Tags: 64-bit, browser, web

Are there any good 64 bit web browsers.  I like using firefox and chrome.

Comment: Internet Explorer. Oh wait, you said *good* browsers, never mind. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Safari 4 on Mac OS X Snow Leopard is 64bit with the plugins running in a separate process to allow for 32bit plugins. I don't know about Safari 4 on Windows, though.

Answer (score 4):

IE has one, Firefox has one, most others probably do. Unfortunately, 32bit plugins don't work in 64bit, and adobe won't make 64bit flash - limiting one's browser slightly. Nobody uses 64bit browsers, really, because there's no need. There's no advantage.

Comment: "adobe won't make 64bit flash - limiting one's browser slightly" -- I think you misspelled "enhancing".  :-)

Comment: hehe, there are two ways of looking at it :P

Comment: There is a 64-bit Flash for Linux only. It's supposedly ‘alpha’ quality, but it's much much better than the 32-bit wrapper and in practice is as stable as I've ever experienced Flash. Which obviously still isn't brilliant.

Comment: Safari 4 on Mac OS X Snow Leopard is 64bit with the plugins running in a  separate process to allow for 32bit plugins. I don't know about Safari 4 on Windows, though

Comment: anyway, the whole reason for 64bit browsers is just not there (as long as the plugins are not 64bit), just as poshi said. "uuhhh, the webpages does not fit into my 2gb ram" .. yeah, right :)

Comment: Not true. All Mac users using computers made in the last couple of years who use Safari (a sizeable proportion) are using a 64 bit browser.

Answer (score 2):

Most 64-bit Linux distros come with a 64-bit version of Firefox. There is also one of those for Windows. Other than that, I don't think there are many 64-bit browsers.

To be honest, you don't really need one. The speed increase would be marginal at best, and most plugins (Flash) aren't 64-bit-compatible yet (although Java finally made a 64-bit version of theirs). You'd gain nothing from using a 64-bit browser, so there's no point. Developers don't want to waste the time, either, so you probably won't see too many in the near future (at least not for Windows).

Comment: Apparently the 64bit of Safari 4 on Mac OS Snow Leopard has (significantly?) better Javascript performance and it runs plugins in a separate process to allow for 32bit plugins.

Comment: @donut: I'll believe it when I see the numbers. But the latter feature is very cool, didn't know about that.

Comment: "To be honest, you don't really need one" - 3.5 years later, is this still a true statement? Just curious :)

Comment: @Brendan: Probably. I mean, if I were a browser vendor, I would start making my browser 64-bit simply because 32-bit is dead, but from a user standpoint, there is still almost no advantage to a 64-bit version of a browser. I'd be interested to see a more recent benchmark, but I remember Mozilla trying a 64-bit build and deciding that the tiny performance advantage wasn't worth the effort to maintain two builds, and that's probably still true.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox has been ported out 64 Bit.  You can find it at:
http://wiki.mozilla-x86-64.com/Firefox:Download

I use version 3.6.3 because version 3.7.x changed the interface to the same one that will be in Firefox 4.0, which I don't like.

I am using the MR Tech Tool Kit extention.  It allows me to run incompatable extensions with newer versions of Firefox (32 bit compatible).  So far, all 32 bit extentions and themes I have seem to work perfectly.

Adobe Flash support had also been ported for 64 bit.  It can be found at:
"http://labs.adobe.com/downloads/flashplayer10.html"

For those of you who are looking for a 64 bit version of Thunderbird, it can be found at:
"http://wiki.mozilla-x86-64.com/Thunderbird:Download"

I am running version 3.1.6 and it runs perfectly.

That is all.

Answer (score 0):

you can download various **Firefox x64** builds [here](http://wiki.mozilla-x86-64.com/Firefox:Download). **Google Chrome x64** is only available for Linux as of now.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, nearly every major browser available supports 64-bit. Some browsers have even been [dropping support for 32-bit](http://www.pcworld.com/article/3010404/browsers/googles-killing-chrome-support-for-32-bit-linux-ubuntu-1204-and-debian-7.html).

[Google Chrome](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/), [Firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/), [Safari (Mac)](https://support.apple.com/en_IN/downloads/safari), and [Internet Explorer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/internet-explorer.aspx) all have 64-bit versions.